# Why does the definition of printf name it __printf

Tags: printf, libc

In the printf.c file of the glibc source code package, the function is declared with underscores in the name. Why?

```
int
__printf (const char *format, ...)
```

Comment: I haven't looked at glibc, but most likely `__printf` is a more private, low-level implementation of the function. Somewhere else glibc must also have an identifier `printf` defined as either a macro wrapping `__printf` or a function that calls it.

Comment: Right after that implementation is a macro that aliases that function to `printf`